# Windbg - The call to LoadLibrary(winext\MSEC.dll) failed

Tags: debugging

I have the following problem. After installing Windbg as a post-mortem debugger and triggering a crash, I let run:

```
!load winext\MSEC.dll
```

and I get the following message:

```
The call to LoadLibrary(winext\MSEC.dll) failed. Win32 error 0n127
"The specified procedure could not be found."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
```

Then I try to call `!exploitable` then I get the following message:

```
No export exploitable found.
```

Can anyone help ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

That error means you don't have the correct "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio" version installed which was used to build that module.

For !exploitable 1.6 that is Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Answer (score -2):

When we extract Bang Exploitable (!Exploitable) it creates 2 Folders:
1) x64
2) x86

Open the folder as per your Project Bit Size.
Now inside that folder, you will get 2 another folders:
1) Release
2) Debug

Copy the files from release folder to the folder that contains the executable of windbg.

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Sometimes you may also need to change the version of windbg for making it compatible with bang exploitable.

Download 
http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi